# Geojson coordinates to R sp coordinates

Tags: r, geojson, r-sp

I am applying the method used in:
[Percentage of overlap between polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694530/percentage-of-overlap-between-polygons)

It works great, except it utilizes R sp with coordinates written as x,x,x,x  y,y,y,y etc. In my case, I have hundreds of geojson polygons with coordinates written as [x,y], [x,y], [[x,y] etc.

What is the way to convert geojson coordinates written as [x,y], [x,y], [[x,y] to R sp with coordinates written as x,x,x,x  y,y,y,y?

Comment: `geojsonsf::geojson_sf("your.json")` will convert GeoJSON to an `sf` object (where `sf` has superseded `sp`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
install.packages("geojsonio")
geojsonio::geojson_read("file.geojson", what = "sp")
```