# Percentage of overlap between polygons visited after each other

Tags: r, gps, polygon, intersection, r-sp

I am looking for an answer on how to calculate the percentage of overlap of different circular polygons?
Concretely, I am referring to this question:

[Percentage of overlap between polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694530/percentage-of-overlap-between-polygons)

In my case, I need to calculate the overlap between two polygons which were visited after each other.

**DATA:
I have a long list (several thousands) of visited polygons (list elements ordered chronologically).**

```
head(polygon.list)
[[1]]
           lat     long
 [1,] 48.11897 11.56869
 [2,] 48.11921 11.56859
 [3,] 48.11931 11.56836
 [4,] 48.11921 11.56812
 [5,] 48.11897 11.56802
 [6,] 48.11873 11.56812
 [7,] 48.11863 11.56836
 [8,] 48.11873 11.56859
 [9,] 48.11897 11.56869

[[2]]
           lat     long
 [1,] 48.11897 11.56869
 [2,] 48.11921 11.56859
 [3,] 48.11931 11.56836
 [4,] 48.11921 11.56812
 [5,] 48.11897 11.56802
 [6,] 48.11873 11.56812
 [7,] 48.11863 11.56836
 [8,] 48.11873 11.56859
 [9,] 48.11897 11.56869

[[3]]
           lat     long
 [1,] 48.11629 11.56797
 [2,] 48.11653 11.56787
 [3,] 48.11663 11.56763
 [4,] 48.11653 11.56739
 [5,] 48.11629 11.56730
 [6,] 48.11605 11.56739
 [7,] 48.11596 11.56763
 [8,] 48.11605 11.56787
 [9,] 48.11629 11.56797
```

I have converted the list elements to Polygon objects using the (sp package)

```
library(sp)

# Create Polygon objects (sp-package) from list elements
for (col in (1:ncol(df))){
  
  polygon <- Polygon(list[[col]])
  list[[col]] <- polygon
}

Polygon.list <- list
> head(Polygon.list)
[[1]]
An object of class "Polygon"
Slot "labpt":
[1] 48.11897 11.56836

Slot "area":
[1] 3.203203e-07

Slot "hole":
[1] FALSE

Slot "ringDir":
[1] 1

Slot "coords":
           lat     long
 [1,] 48.11897 11.56869
 [2,] 48.11921 11.56859
 [3,] 48.11931 11.56836
 [4,] 48.11921 11.56812
 [5,] 48.11897 11.56802
 [6,] 48.11873 11.56812
 [7,] 48.11863 11.56836
 [8,] 48.11873 11.56859
 [9,] 48.11897 11.56869


[[2]]
An object of class "Polygon"
Slot "labpt":
[1] 48.11897 11.56836

Slot "area":
[1] 3.203203e-07

Slot "hole":
[1] FALSE

Slot "ringDir":
[1] 1

Slot "coords":
           lat     long
 [1,] 48.11897 11.56869
 [2,] 48.11921 11.56859
 [3,] 48.11931 11.56836
 [4,] 48.11921 11.56812
 [5,] 48.11897 11.56802
 [6,] 48.11873 11.56812
 [7,] 48.11863 11.56836
 [8,] 48.11873 11.56859
 [9,] 48.11897 11.56869


[[3]]
An object of class "Polygon"
Slot "labpt":
[1] 48.11629 11.56763

Slot "area":
[1] 3.203195e-07

Slot "hole":
[1] FALSE

Slot "ringDir":
[1] 1

Slot "coords":
           lat     long
 [1,] 48.11629 11.56797
 [2,] 48.11653 11.56787
 [3,] 48.11663 11.56763
 [4,] 48.11653 11.56739
 [5,] 48.11629 11.56730
 [6,] 48.11605 11.56739
 [7,] 48.11596 11.56763
 [8,] 48.11605 11.56787
 [9,] 48.11629 11.56797
```

However, I don't know how to apply the following solution suggested for three concrete Polygons to my example of an unknown number of Polygons: (see [Percentage of overlap between polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694530/percentage-of-overlap-between-polygons))

```
poly <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(polygon1)), "a"),Polygons(list(Polygon(polygon2)), "b"),Polygons(list(Polygon(polygon3)), "c")),1L:3L)

## areas for the original shapes:
areas_poly <- vector(length = length(poly)) 
for (x in seq_along(poly)) areas_poly[x]<-area(poly[x])

## areas for the overlapping regions:
idx <- combn(seq_along(poly),2)
areas_intersect <- sapply(1:ncol(idx), function(x) {
  area(intersect(poly[idx[1,x]], poly[idx[2,x]])) 
})

## get overlaps in percentages:
overlap_perc <- 
  round(do.call(cbind, lapply(seq_len(ncol(idx)), function(x)  
  rbind(
    areas_intersect[x] / areas_poly[idx[1,x]] * 100, 
    areas_intersect[x] / areas_poly[idx[2,x]] * 100
  )
)), 2)
```

**GOAL: I need a list or dataframe, containing the percentage of the intersection area of one polygon with the polygon included in the list element before the respective polygon**

**ADD-ON: Polygons in the list do often not overlap (as in example above), which is why a solution also considering the case of a "NULL" intersection area is needed**

I have tried several apply()-solutions on my own, so any concrete coding help really appreciated!